# 6DOF using accelerometer and gyroscope

Tags: iphone, accelerometer

Has any one developed 6DOF pose estimation using only the iPhone sensors, not video? Drift from the accelerometer and gyroscope are understood.

The gyroscope provides fairly reliable relative orientation rates. I've been able to develop with the gyroscope data.

However, I'm having more problems deriving translation from the accelerometer. Double integration of the acceleration leads to useless position data very quickly (less than half a second).

I have attempted to remove the bias with a calibration step, but the position is still poor. What's worse, is the bias isn't constant. It changes over time, and the noise drowse the signal.

I'm interested if anyone has been able to develop a 6DOF with only the accelerometer and gyroscope that works reliably for 5-10 seconds with little drift in both translation and orientation.

Comment: Would whoever voted this as "too localised" like to give a reason? It doesn't seem localised to me.

Comment: cbroaddus can you post the code that you use to do the double integration. The way Im doing it is to use the userAcceleration property to get the device acceleration and then convert this into the world coordinates using the inverse of the gyro attitude (after having reset it to world coordinates with reference attitude) and THEN i integrate the accelerometer values. I havnt finished coding it so i cant paste my code yet and I havnt tested it so Im not putting this in the answer section...

Comment: If you use the userAcceleration property the bias and the gravity component have been estimated and removed. What you mentioned should work fine. The attitude yaw drifts, but the pitch and roll are stable. I have done something similar, and the noise, quantization, bias and accuracy make the translation completely unreliable. If you use the raw accelerometer data, you have to remove the gravity component yourself in combination with the gyro and/or external measurements.

Comment: The gyro gives very stable values. Its the integration of the acceleration that completely blows up because there is nothing to close the loop and indicate to it whether its right or wrong. My model just floats off into the distance almost immediately. I suppose one would have to stick a more reliable apriori model on the system such as that a users hands almost always returns to the same are more or less so that means a very leaky integrator would be valid here.

Comment: I got similar results also; without low-frequency filtering the results are completely useless, with sufficient filtering they're mostly useless.

Answer (score 1):

The gyro yaw using DeviceMotion has a drift when you first start updating, try not to take those samples and everyone will be happy.

Answer (score 0):

I made a post about this: [Get orientation device in the iPhone for Opengl Es](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951179/get-orientation-device-in-the-iphone-for-opengl-es), I having the same issue, I´m just trying to make a filter but it´s not working good, there is a book about these [http://www.amazon.com/iOS-Sensor-Programming-Augmented-Location/dp/1449382657](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449382657), but I didn´t read this book.